# Include typings from private dependencies

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have a typescript package A with a private dependency B. And we want A to export its typings along with B typings. 
Using a standard build with declarations:true, the B typings are only referenced but not defined in the output. So it's not possible to know them unless you have access to package B.

Is there any way without making a custom script for that, to include the typings of B in the distribution of A?

Comment: You could just re-export in A everything you need from B: In your main types.d.ts of A: `export * from "B"`

Comment: Then I'll a get  A.d.ts with export {thing} from "private-package". But I can not distribute that file becase it resolves to a missing dependency